# Domain of $\sec x$ vs. domain of $\sec^{-1}(\sec x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Why is $\sec x$ undefined at $x = \pi/2$ but $\sec^{-1}(\sec (\pi/2)) = \pi/2$, according to WolframAlpha?

Comment: What makes you think that $\sec^{-1}(\sec(\pi/2)) = \pi/2$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov WolframAlpha

Comment: Machines are never as good at interpreting math as humans.

Comment: WolframAlpha is a tool, don't use tools  blindfolded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WolframAlpha (and the associated Wolfram Language and Mathematica crowd) define `Sec[Pi/2]` to be `ComplexInfinity` (written $\tilde \infty$ if you try it in WolframAlpha specifically) rather than simply saying that it's undefined, and take `ArcSec[ComplexInfinity]` to be `Pi/2`. This gives us other fascinating results: for example, WolframAlpha thinks that $\sec^{-1}(1/0) = \pi/2$ as well.

This is roughly equivalent to working with the [projectively extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line) $\mathbb R \cup \{\tilde \infty\}$ (where the infinity in question has no sign, since `-ComplexInfinity` simplifies to `ComplexInfinity` ) and defining various operations like division by $0$ to return $\tilde \infty$ as a result. The price we pay for this extension is that there are some inputs for which even simple arithmetic operations become *even more undefined*. For example, `1/0 - 1/0` simplifies to `Indeterminate`, because $\tilde\infty - \tilde\infty$ has no definition in the projectively extended real numbers.

When thinking of $x\mapsto \sec(x)$ as a partial function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, though, which is what mathematicians usually do, there is no alternative to saying that $\sec^{-1}(\sec(\pi/2))$ is undefined.